# How to pass Ajax Json object to the Controller Class in .Net Core?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

We are trying to make a Ajax request to our Core Web API and get the `data` Json result back to the Controller for further processing, Which include Deserialization of the Json object result, Ajax request is working fine and we are able to get the required Json data in `data`.

Can anyone here please advise the changes or the alternatives to achieve this?

**View (Ajax Request)**

```
@section scripts
{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    GetEventDetails('@Url.Content("~/")');
    });



    function GetEventDetails(contextRoot) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: contextRoot + "api/EventsAPI",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        debugger;
        var datavalue = data;
        contentType: "application/json";
        //Send data to controller ???
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
    });
    }
</script>
}
```

**Controller.cs**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{    
    /*Do all stuff before returning view 
    1. Get Json Data from Ajax request
    2. Deserialize the obtained Json Data
    3. return to view
    */
    return View("Index");
}
```

**Update:**

I have tried the solution given by @J. Doe, but still unable to get the result set. Please check the screenshot and below code..

**Ajax Request:**

```
function GetEventDetails(contextRoot) {        
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: contextRoot + "api/EventsAPI",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
                var datavalue = data;
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8";                 
                console.log(data);
                var EventJson = data;
                console.log(EventJson);
                $.ajax({             
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "@Url.Action("Index")",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: EventJson,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                        
                        //data: EventJson,                       
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data.responseText);
                        console.log('Data received: ');
                        console.log(data.responseText);                           
                    },
                    failure: function (errMsg) {
                        console.log(errMsg);
                }
            });
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
}
```

**Class Properties:**

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Embedded _embedded { get; set; }
    public Links _links { get; set; }
    public Page page { get; set; }
}
```

**Here is Action Result Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index(RootObject model)
{
    if (model != null)
    {
        return Json("Success");
    }
    else
    {
        return Json("An Error Has occoured");
    }
    //return View("Index");
}
```

Error Snapshot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbHLu.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Add [FromBody] the controller you are returning to. This will make the controller expect a JSON object.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index([FromBody]RootObject model)
    {
        if (model != null)
        {
            return Json("Success");
        }
        else
        {
            return Json("An Error Has occoured");
        }
        //return View("Index");
    }
```

2) If this doesn't work you are not posting a correct json object/you are not posting a json object use `console.dir(EventJson);` to inspect the object you are passing in the console of the browser.

3) How to create a JSON object in JS: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp

Answer (score 0):

> We are trying

***Hello soviet sojuz!***

But back to question - A 2 months ago i created sample on GitHub with ajax with .Net Core - https://github.com/CShepartd/ASP.Net_Core_-_Ajax_Example

**In short:**

Make action with objects in controller:

```
    public IActionResult Ajax(string name1, string name2)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Next in view send `name1` and `name2` to action

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var data = {
                name1: $("input[name='name1']", this).val(),
                name2: $("input[name='name2']",this).val()
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Home/Ajax',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: data,
                success: function(response) {
                    alert(response);
                    console.log('Data received: ');
                    console.log(response);
                },
                failure: function(response) {
                    //...
                },
                error: function(response) {
                    //...
                }
            });
        });
```